# getResources() is throwing an error

Tags: java, android

I have the following code which is used for creating a custom `ListView` in my app with two tabs:

```
package com.test.testing;

import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Html;

public class SetRows {
    int image;
    String name;
    String id;

    public int getImage () {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage (int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getName () {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getID () {
        return id;
    }

    public void setID (String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public SetRows(int image, String name, String id) {

        super();
        this.image = image;
        this.name = Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.colorcol)) + " COLOR: \n\t" + name;
        this.id = "MEANS: \n\t" +  id;
    }

}
```

The following line:

`this.name = Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.colorcol)) + " COLOR: \n\t" + name;`

gives me the following error:

`The method getResources() is undefined for the type SetRows`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your code so you have a reference to the current context, which, in turn, will give you access to `getResources`.

For instance

```
public SetRows(Context currentContext,int image, String name, String id) {

        super();

        this.image = image;
        this.name = Html.fromHtml(currentContext.getResources().getString(R.string.colorcol)) + " COLOR: \n\t" + name;
        this.id = "MEANS: \n\t" +  id;
    }
```

You'd have to change the instantiation of the class to

```
contents.add(new SetRows(this,inIconShow, sColor, sExplain));
```

Comment: Which you'd have to change to contents.add(new SetRows(this,inIconShow, sColor, sExplain));

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
getResources()
```

it means

```
this.getResources()
```

Here **this** is an instance of SetRows (your class),
and your class SetRows has no method named getResources.

This is what the error means.

Comment: See response from ZouZou and/or DigCamara, could be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`getResources()` is a method available for all classes that extends the `Context` class. Your class doesn't.

The common workaround is to pass an instance of your `context` when creating your `SetRows` object.

```
public SetRows(Context context, int image, String name, String id) {

        super();
        this.image = image;
        this.name = Html.fromHtml(context.getResources().getString(R.string.colorcol)) + " COLOR: \n\t" + name;
        this.id = "MEANS: \n\t" +  id;
    }
```

Then in your activity, you can just do :

```
new SetRows(this, /****/);
```

Comment: I played around and fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Pass in a `Context` through the constructor and call:

```
context.getResources(...);
```